# Print letters with variable divs problem in web

Tags: laravel, vue.js, printing, vuetify.js, report

in our organization we develop E-letter (E-book) System for Official correspondence based on (unit, section, Department). we have problems in print letter:

1. height of content is variable, and may be the letter one page or many pages.
2. there is many variable divs in print: Attachments, notes, signatures, copy to another departments, variable footer, etc. this divs may exists or not.

how to manage this variable divs if exists execute correctly. example of problems: content higher than signature image & name and cut the signature image, or count of notes is variable, duplicate signature in all pages we need it in last page **also another big problem position of divs there is many problems and div cut another divs or piece of it.**

can you help us! we need an advance tool for printing in web. the system developed by Laravel 10 backend, Vue (Vutify). if there is any suggestions to solve this BIG problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@media print` in CSS to control which parts should be visible when printing in the browser.

for example you can use .no-print class for all the div elements you want them to be not included in print
and in your css styling you can set that using  `@media print`

```
@media print {
  .no-print{
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

You can try styling and controlling everything you need using  `@media print`

Comment: thank you! but the problem is position of divs also div cut another div

Comment: can you provide  some code examples and screenshots ?